# How to override ingress rules helm-chart template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Here is my ingress.yml file

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{- if .Values.ingress.host }} {{ tpl .Values.ingress.host . }} {{- end }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ssl-redirect
            port:
              name: use-annotation
      {{- range $port := .Values.container.app.port }}
      - path: {{ tpl $port.path $ }}
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Release.Name }}
            port:
              number: {{ int $port.port }}
      {{- end }}
{{ end }}
```

I want to override this rules some service here is what I try to do in my values.yml file

```
ingress:
  scheme: internal
  host: test.com
  paths:
    - path: /
      pathType: Prefix
      backend:
        service:
          name: ssl-redirect
          port:
            name: use-annotation
    - path: /
      pathType: Prefix
      backend:
        service:
          name: test
          port:
            number: 3000
```

but after I deploy it's not override at all may be in wrong format not sure

##### UPDATE

I try to this way but It still didn't override rules in ingress

```
hosts:
  - host: test.com
    paths:
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ssl-redirect
            port:
              name: use-annotation
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-dev
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ingress.yaml` should be something like

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $name }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
  {{- with $_annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $name }}
              servicePort: 80
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: test.example.io
      paths: [/path]

  # tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local
```

**Another example :**

**Ingress.yaml** : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/ghost/templates/ingress.yaml

**values.yaml** : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/ghost/values.yaml

Comment: thank you very much , In my question I just copy some part of Ingress.yaml sorry about that

Comment: no issues at all.

Comment: I update my question. I already tried but still didn't override would you mind to help me check please

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming that this is not the whole ingress.yaml template because if it is, you are missing the `apiVersion`, `kind` and `metadata` block entirely. :)

helm can create a baseline chart with `helm create <chartName>`. in this baseline chart, there is a `ingress.yaml` template with a corresponding `values.yaml` which works just fine and follows helm best practices. i recommend you use that one to ease and speed up your workflow instead of writing your own template, even if you do not understand it at first. the generated templates by `helm create` are worth studying because there is a lot to learn from them and they are a good showcase of how to solve some common problems when writing helm charts and how to follow best practices for labeling, annotations etc.

anyways, if you want to stick to that data structure and create your own template, this is the template that worked during my tests. i used the `helm template` command to check if there are any rendering errors whilst providing your values.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
    http:
      paths:
        {{- range .Values.ingress.paths }}
        - path: {{ .path }}
          pathType: {{ .pathType }}
          backend:
            service: {{ .backend.service | toYaml | nindent 14 }}
        {{- end }}
```